# Mapping a Login to a User

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, users, logins

On my production system I login to SQL Server with `CPSDOM\mconnors`. When I execute `SELECT CURRENT_USER;` it returns `CPSDOM\mconnors`.

We use Windows authentication on our DBs.

On my test system I login to SQL Server with `CPSDOM\mconnors`. When I execute `SELECT CURRENT_USER;` it returns `dbo`.

So I my test system I went to `security/logins/ Login Properties/UserMaping` and entered in `CPSDOM\mconnors` for the user. When I run `SELECT CURRENT_USER`, I still get back `dbo`. I went back to the `Login properties/UserMapping` to verify the change was still there and it was.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same result on both systems, your choices are:

1. If you always want to know the server-level Windows account in use, change your code to use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` in both places instead of relying on database mapping (or use `SUSER_SNAME()`).
2. Add your login to the `sysadmin` role on the production system.
3. Create a new login on your test system (or at least be sure you know the `sa` password), *remove* this login from the `sysadmin` role, and make sure they are no longer the database owner (e.g. `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::dbname TO sa;`). You may then need to manually add them as a user and add permissions within the database (sorry, this is my least preferred option, and I didn't feel like messing up my own login on my system to test it).

Answer (score 1):

It means you have database owner ("db_owner") privileges on the database.

You can see this in "User Mapping" tab in Database Properties.

[image]

And here you can see current user and login.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[CURRENT_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx) will give you the name of the current security context., which if you are member of the db_owner group is dbo.

If you want your NT login to be displayed try using [SYSTEM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) or [SUSER_NAME()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) instead:

`SELECT SYSTEM_USER, SUSER_NAME(), CURRENT_USER`
`CPSDOM\mconnors| CPSDOM\mconnors| dbo`